# Linq Where then Select on a HashSet

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a list of products that match a certain category id. The problem I'm having is that I'm using the select clause before the where, essentially trying to filter once I've already got all the results.  Usually its straight forward but  since this navigation property is a HashSet its proving more tricky. My repo.GetAll() gets all the products from my database. CategoryProducts is a linking table between products and Categories, its also a navigation property on the product table

```
ProductRepository repo = new ProductRepository();
var products = 
   repo.GetAll()
       .Select(c => c.CategoryProducts
                     .Where(p => p.CategoryId == 35));
```

The above just returns all my products, any help is appreciated.

Comment: please take care of your formatting ... is this right here? or was there a problem with the parens and `.Where` is suppost to be after the `.Select` (the `c` indicates that a bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns an enumerable that corresponds to all your products, each item of that enumerable is an enumerable itself, containing zero or more categories with `ID` of 35.

You can change your query to get only products that have category 35 in them:

```
var products = repo
    .GetAll()
    .Where(p => p.CategoryProducts.Any(c => c.CategoryId == 35));
```